# How to create a for loop from an array resulting from a split function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in my excel sheet which contains references to some products in type "CTR_01" with the first 3 letters represent the domain which the product belongs to. In addition I have a userform that allows me to edit some information I have in the database.
I need to compare the domain chosen in the combobox to the array I got from the split function used on the reference, however it doesn't seem to work.

```vb
For Each cell In Range("G3:G800")
    chaine() = split(cell.Value, "_")
Next

For i = LBound(chaine) To UBound(chaine)
   While dom = chaine(i)
      pro = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(prolist, Sheets("Data").Range("Produit_edit"))
      //Something to do
   Wend
Next i
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to match in the second Loop. Your First is wrong, but I want to understand what second is doing in order to make it work for you.

Comment: You have not defined Pro and Prolist, where did they come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do somthing like this:

```
For Each cell In Range("G3:G800")

     chaine = Split(cell.Value, "_")

   If dom = chaine(0) Then

        ' do things if your dom = chaine i.e Domain for each cell

   End If

Next
```